# Difference between BrokeredMessage class in Microsoft.ServiceBus and Message class in Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I've got started with Azure Service Bus in Azure. Having gone through some references over the Internet, it seems that people use **BrokeredMessage** class in Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging rather than **Message** class in Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.

- BrokeredMessage class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?view=azure-dotnet
- Message class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet

I can send both of message 'types' to Azure Service Bus and also work with them over Azure Service Bus. Also, both can be used in Asynchronous operation. What are the main differences between the two types?

[Update] This article gives best practices of Azure Service Bus when exchaning **brokered** message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements). I'm unsure if it is also referred to **Message** in Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.

Comment: I think the difference is in the library (SDK): Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is the newer version of the library built using .Net Standard while Microsoft.ServiceBus is the older version of the library built using .Net Framework.

Comment: Thank you @GauravMantri. I kind of thought so but I'm unsure about that :). This quite new article (written 1 month ago) used BrokeredMessage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements

Comment: The article you referred to is actually last edited one month ago :). You can look at the history here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commits/master/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements.md.

Comment: Yes saw it. But I still have doubts about which should be used. Is Microsoft not encouraging new library?

Comment: Since the new library only supports Queues & Topics, if you are only using those, then my recommendation would be to use the new one. However if you're using Relays and Event Hubs, old library should be used as they are not supported in the new one. Plus other consideration is the .Net framework are you using.

Comment: But I agree that Microsoft could provide some concrete guidance around these two libraries and tell us when to use which.

Comment: Here's info on wire compatibility between a client using BrokeredMessage and a client using Message: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/239#issuecomment-320820562

Comment: How can I work with capabilities like "add to dead letter queue" in the new "Message" world?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it's a new project to use Azure Service Bus, I would recommend the following:

- Prefer the new .NET Standard client (`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`) with `Message`.
- Be careful with documentation and various resources. They mostly cater to the old client (hopefully MSFT doco soon to change).
- If you need transport transactions spanning different entities, the new client can't provide it yet.
- If you need management operations, the new client won't provide it. Ever. Instead you'd have to use Management library or wait till a replacement package for `NamespaceManager` is out.
- If you have old systems emitting messages sent as serialized data and not Stream, implementations using new Client have to know about it and use extension method provided by the client to process those messages. New client only deals with `Stream` based messages.

Comment: Is there any guideline to the opposite scenario of the one that you have described: old client reads body as `String`, but the new client sends all as `Stream`

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on how we can use the new library to emulate String body type. Have asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037363/send-a-message-with-a-new-client-that-is-read-by-an-old-client-brokeredmessage

Comment: See my [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037363/send-a-message-with-a-new-library-microsoft-azure-servicebus-that-is-read-by-a/56048953#56048953)

Comment: Just a question. Can BrokeredMessage handle DeadLetter queue too. Don't know.

Comment: `BrokeredMessage` doesn't handle queues, it can perform operations on a given message. You might want to raise that as a separate and a bit more detailed question. Also, I would strongly discourage from using that type as it belongs to the legacy SDK/libarry. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As Gaurav Mantiri mentioned that Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus is the newer version of the library built using .Net Standard.

You could get the detail information from [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet).

> This is the next generation Service Bus .NET client library that focuses on queues & topics. This library is built using **.NET Standard 1.3**.

Comment: Thank you. The new library was started 5 months ago and this article was just out 1 month ago (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements). This gives me sort of surprise whether Microsoft still encourages older library. Moreover, am I right to say BrokeredMessage and Message are interchangeable for the purpose of handling message?