# Is it possible to output Message/BrokeredMessage with Azure Functions V2?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

It isn't clear from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) how to output a structured message. In an old function I've used `BrokeredMessage`, and the docs say to use `Message` for V2 functions, however there is no guidance on *how* to use this. Is this correct:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Job))]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Job(
    // ...
    IAsyncCollector<Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message> serializedJobCollector
)
```

The goal is to be able to set some metadata properties like the ID, which I've done before (with V1 and `BrokeredMessage`) for duplicate detection, but I'm not sure if this is correct or I need to serialize to a string or what...

Comment: I think you need to use Message with a stream https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045149/difference-between-brokeredmessage-class-in-microsoft-servicebus-and-message-cla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have found the right way, as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output---usage) says

> for 2.x, use Message instead of BrokeredMessage

To take an example

```
    [FunctionName("FunctionTest")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        [ServiceBus(queueOrTopicName:"queueName",Connection ="ServiceBusConnection")]IAsyncCollector<Message> outputMessages,
        ILogger log)
    {
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var message = new Message
            {
                Body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody),
                MessageId = "MyMessageId"
            };
            await outputMessages.AddAsync(message);
    }
```