# Possible to consume BrokeredMessage from Message

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Service Bus consumer targeting .NET. The consumer uses `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage` to deserialize and handle the message:

```cs
BrokeredMessage message = ...;
var json = message.GetBody<string>();
```

This works great when using `BrokeredMessage` on the publisher side:

```cs
var msg = new BrokeredMessage(json);
await _bus.SendAsync(msg);
```

Now, I'm porting the publisher to .NET Core and switching to using the newer type `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message`:

```cs
var msg = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
msg.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
```

When doing this, my consumer fails with the following error:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. The input source is not correctly formatted.

Is it possible to produce messages using `Message` and consume it using `BrokeredMessage`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048953/59563) answer.

Comment: The answer worked perfectly. I have marked this question as a duplicate. Thank you for your help, Sean.