# System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException while receiving message from Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus, brokeredmessage, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have two separate applications one **.Net Core** other in **.Net Framework**. I have created a service bus sender in .Net core console application. It is sending message to service bus using latest `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs` and `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.ServiceBus` nuget packages. Here is sample code for sender.

```
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request)));
var client = new TopicClient(connectionString, TopicName);
await client.SendAsync(message);
```

The other application written in .NET Framework 4.7 is listening to same service bus. It is using nuget packages `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs` and `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.ServiceBus` both version 2.3.0 for .Net Framework. Sample code below.

```
public class ListenJob
{
    public static void Listen([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%")] BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        var messageBody = message.GetBody<string>();
    }
}
```

On sending message from .Net core console application. The other application is able to detect the message but I get following error on line `var messageBody = message.GetBody<string>();` in listener.

> Exception while executing function:
>   Applications
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception
>   while executing function:
>   Applications --->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : There was an
>   error deserializing the object of type System.String. The input source
>   is not correctly formatted. ---> System.Xml.XmlException : The input
>   source is not correctly formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sending code the message body is sent as a stream (the bytes are sent as-is and are not encoded). The code you're using to receive with an older Azure Service Bus library is expecting to deserialize a string from those bytes. You should use the same method of sending and receiving when it comes to encoding. I.e. you should get a `Stream` using `message.GetBody<Stream>` and read the bytes from the stream and deserializing if needed. More information [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/239#issuecomment-320820562).

To be able to retrieve is as a string using `message.GetBody<string>` as-is, you'd need to change your sender's code to send DataContract binary serialized string. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56048953/59563) on how to.